# Why does my JavaScript function only work once?

Tags: javascript, php

```
<a href="javascript: codeChange()">

//write an img tag to the screen

<script>
// @para1 of verCode: numbers of the characters
// @para2 of verCode: the width of the picture
// @para3 of verCode: the height pf the picture
// the php code is from $code = verCode(),in which the function  verCode is generating some verification code.

var code = "<?=$code?>"
document.write("<img src='backend/verificationCode.php?code=" + code + "' id='codePic'>")

//when the a tag is clicked, the function below executes

function codeChange() {
  var code = "<?=verCode(4, 70, 20)?>"
  document.getElementById("codePic").src = "backend/verificationCode.php?code=" + code + "" 

//the url links to a php page to change the code into picture

}
</script>

</a>
```

What's odd is that when I click the image (within the a tags) for the first time, it changed, but then after that, it won't. What's wrong with my code? Why does this happen?

Comment: it works everytime, but it keeps setting the same image, that's why you don't see any change after the first time.

Comment: Sorry your question got put on hold. To answer your question, `<? ?>` blocks run under PHP, so things like `<?=verCode(4, 70, 20)?>` will only run once, on the server, when the page is requested. Your JavaScript block will not call back to PHP to recalculate a new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
verCode(4, 70, 20);
```

seems to be returning same value so even if image is changing. You are not noticing it.
hope it helps :)

Comment: no,every time the verCode is called,it generate a different verification code,I made it's possible to do that.

Comment: with the comment below my question,now I got it